# Explicit conversion int to SqlInt32

Tags: c#, t-sql, clr

Does anybody knows how to explicitly convert int to SqlInt32? Compiler throws error of conversion.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction()]
    static public int RarFiles(SqlString TARGET, SqlString SRC, SqlString SIZE)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
        p.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe";
        p.Arguments = String.Format("a -cfg- -ep1 -idcdp -m5 -r -s -v{0} {1} {2}", SIZE, TARGET, SRC);
        Process x = Process.Start(p);
        SqlInt32 res = x.ExitCode;
        return res;
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is converting the `int` to `SqlInt32` and not the other conversion on the next line with the return statement?

Comment: I don't get it.
your method result is `int` and `x.ExitCode` is `int`. so why you convert it to `SqlInt32` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your method to return an SqlInt32, you'll need to declare it as returning one. Your current code defines the return type of the method as `int`

```
static public int RarFiles(SqlString TARGET, SqlString SRC, SqlString SIZE)
              ^^^
```

This line of code will work fine:

```
SqlInt32 res = x.ExitCode;
```

Because as John has noted, there's an implicit conversion from int to SqlInt32

But then the next time:

```
return res;
```

Will try to convert the SqlInt32 to int, because the method returns an int, but in that direction, the conversion is explicit (you have to cast) and as you haven't supplied an explicit conversion, you'll get an error. The solution you seek is probably not to make the explicit conversion, but to fix the problem with the declared return type of the method

Answer (score 0):

```
public static implicit operator SqlInt32 (
    int x
)
```

Parameters

```
x
```

Type: System.Int32
An integer value.
Return Value
Type: System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32